# @MockBean return always false

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking

I'm trying to test my app, but when I use @MockBean, all the functions return false.
This is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppParkingApplicationTests {

@MockBean
Vehicle vehicle;
@MockBean
VehicleController vehicleController;

@Test
public void getValidVehicleTest(){
    //Arrange
    boolean resp=false;
    when(vehicle.getTipo()).thenReturn("Carro");
    //Act
    resp=vehicleController.getValidVehicle(vehicle.getTipo());
    //Assert
    assertEquals(true, resp);
}
```

And this is the function

```
public boolean getValidVehicle(String tipo){
        boolean result=false;
        if(tipo.equals("Carro") || tipo.equals("Moto")){
            result= true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default return for a mocked method when the return type is the primitive boolean is false.

I dont think you want to mock your Controller since this seems to be the class under test. Just replace

```
@MockBean
VehicleController vehicleController;
```

with

```
@Autowired
VehicleController vehicleController;
```

Comment: Fine answer +1. I love your avatar. What is it ?

Comment: I think the same about my controller... but it has some methods that connect to the BD, so... what can I do in that case?

Comment: @AndresCastañedaMarin Mock the repository that calls the DB instead.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks! It's from a Perry Bible Fellowship comic: http://pbfcomics.com/comics/wise-shitashi/